# My PHP won't log my $_SESSIONs

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

So I'm building a website for PHP & MySQL practice and I'm attempting to set up a member's system. What is supposed to happen is the user goes to the login page and logs in using a registered username and password (Which works in the registration process) and then the page will refresh and take them to the 'members' area. Here's my code:

```
<?php  
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username'])) {   
    echo "<h1>Member Area</h1>"; 
    echo "<p>Thanks for logging in! You are <b>" . $_SESSION['Username'] . "</b> and your email address is <b>" . $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] . "</b>.</p>";    

} elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {  
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  
    $password = md5(md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])));  

    $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");  

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1) {  
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);  
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];  

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;  
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;  
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;  

        echo "<center>";
        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";  
        echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";  
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;login.php' />";
        echo "</center>";  
    } else {  
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";  
    }  
} else {  
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<h1>Login</h1>";
    echo "<p>Thanks for visiting! Please either login below, or <a href=\"register.php\">click here to register</a>.</p>";
    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"login.php\" name=\"loginform\" id=\"loginform\">";
    echo "<label for=\"username\">Username:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" id=\"username\" /><br />";
    echo "<label for=\"password\">Password:</label><input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" id=\"password\" /><br /> "; 
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"login\" id=\"login\" value=\"Login\" />";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</center>";
}  
?>
```

So basically, the page loads and checks if the user is already logged in and if they are, it loads the members area. If not, it checks to see if the user is trying to log in and if not it shows the login form.
My problem is that, every time I or somebody else tries to log in, the page reloads, but instead of taking them to the 'member' area, it takes them back to the login form...
Also, at the top of the document I have a line which is:
`<?php include "base.php"; ?>`
and in the base.php file I have a `session_start()`, but maybe that is irrelevant?
Any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT:
The code to register a user is in a different php file. Again, the base.php file with `session_start();` is included at the top of the document:
    
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = md5(md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])));
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

```
    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."'");  

    if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1) {  
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
        echo "<p>Sorry, that username is taken. Please go back and try again.</p>";  
     } else {  
        $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')");  
        if($registerquery) {  
            echo "<h1>Success</h1>";  
            echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";  
        } else {  
            echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
            echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";      
        }         
     }  
} else {  

   echo "<h1>Register</h1>";

   echo "<p>Please enter your details below to register.</p> "; 

    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"register.php\" name=\"registerform\" id=\"registerform\">";
    echo "    <label for=\"username\">Username:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" id=\"username\" /><br /> "; 
    echo "    <label for=\"password\">Password:</label><input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" id=\"password\" /><br />  ";
    echo "    <label for=\"email\">Email Address:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" id=\"email\" /><br />";  
    echo "    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"register\" id=\"register\" value=\"Register\" />"; 
    echo "</form>";   
}  
?>
```

Comment: have you added `session_start()`?

Comment: Also, don't use mysql_ functions with new code. They are deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: Try turning on errors.  If you're including a file that has `session_start()` then it should work.  But maybe it's not including the file? Or there's an error in that file...

Comment: Can you show the code used to register a user?

Comment: Now included in the edit

Comment: Are you doing the md5(md5(pw)) on insert?

Comment: Could you elaborate for me?

Comment: You check for the md5 of the md5 of the password when loggin in, do you also do the md5 of the md5 of the password before inserting it after a user registers?

Comment: Yes, I do. `$password = md5(md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])));`

Comment: Did you try adding the `session_start()` in the beginning of this file, even if you say it is included with `base.php`?

Comment: Yes, after it was suggested many times, I gave it ago, but to no avail.

Comment: Well based on these snippets you've shown us here, there's no other possibility than `$_SESSION`-variables containing something other than you're expecting or they're containing nothing at all. There might be some other issues elsewhere but that can't be seen from these lines of code.

Comment: When you compare the pw, try echoing it out. Also do a `select * from users where username = $username`, and make sure it's all fetching the correct username + pw.

Comment: Tried it again. Everything's working, but it still isn't...

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing a

```
session_start()
```

at the top of that php script

Comment: At the top of the document I have a line which is: <?php include "base.php"; ?> and in the base.php file I have a session_start(), but maybe that is irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

Always ensure that `session_start()` is at the top of all other pages concerned also. I would use `isset` as apposed to `!empty`.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with !empty as variables which doesn't exist are considered as empty.

Answer (score 1):

For every page you want to carry over the session to, you have to do

```
session_start();
```

even if the session is already created.

assuming you will want a logout page, when you are going to log the users out on a page like logout.php, you must have:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

The session_start(); is necessary to destroy the session

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated, use MySQLi or PDO instead!!!
Also a `session_start();` might be useful to work with sessions.